# how to measure if a matrix reach it limit in an iteration process?

Tags: limits, matrix-calculus

There is a iteration process :
S<sub>k+1</sub> =BS<sub>k</sub>A<sup>T</sup>+B<sup>T</sup>S<sub>k</sub>A

S is the similarity matrix of G<sub>A</sub> and G<sub>B</sub>. And A and B are adjacency matrices of graphs and S<sub>0</sub> is a matrix whose entries are all equal to 1. Sequence S<sub>k</sub> does not always converge, but the even and odd subsequences do converge.

I want to know how to measure if S<sub>k</sub> reach it limit in the iteration process?

Comment: You need a [matrix norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm). Try sup norm. Not sure how rigorous you're trying to be, but this basically reduces convergence to a one-dimensional problem.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I want to use that iteration process to measure the similarity between graph vertices. The similarity between graph vertices express by S. Through each iteration, the similarity is more precise. So I want to get the limit of S.